# How to know when IMFTransform is finished with Input Sample?

Tags: com, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to decode a h.264 stream using Windows Media Foundation. I'm slowly wading through the API, and one thing I cannot seem to figure out is how to know when the `IMFTransform` is finished using a `IMFTransform` provided by `ProcessInput`. The documentation says "the MFT stores the sample and holds a reference count on the IMFSample pointer." Ignoring the fact that this is absolutely horrendous, how are you supposed to determine when it's actually done, given that you cannot get the reference count of a com_ptr so far as I am aware. You can technically call `AddRef` and the `Release`, using what `Release` returns, but per the documentation the value returned is meant to be used for "testing purposes only". So what is the correct way of determining this?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. You normally don't want to know when specific input processing is finished per se. You either want to know when it's safe to reuse input buffer, and this is where COM reference counting jumps in. Or (and) you want to know when output is ready and this is where `ProcessOutput` does the job.

Comment: Why do you need to manage IMFSample lifetime ?